# Bar with negative stack and positive labels

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to make in R (Shiny) a reversed stacked bar highchart. I already found how to make the graph, but I can't find out how to make the labels on the x-axis positive, like here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack

I've tried to apply the `abs()` function, but it didn't work so far. Does anyone have a solution?

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Example") %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = ""), labels = list(format = "{value}"))  %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(series=list(stacking='normal'), 
                 column = list( dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), 
                 enableMouseTracking = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(reversed=FALSE, opposite=TRUE, reversed=FALSE) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name="neutral", id='neutral', color=c("#766A62"), data=list(2, 8))  %>%      
  hc_add_series(name="Neutral",linkedTo='neutral',color=c("#ffeeff"),data=list(-5, -3))
```

I want the values of the bars and the labels on the x-axis all to be positive. Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Example") %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = ""),labels = list(format = "{value}"))  %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(series=list(stacking='normal'),column = list( dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), 
                                                           enableMouseTracking = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(list(categories = c("0-4", "5-9"),
                reversed=FALSE ), 
           list(reversed=FALSE,opposite=TRUE,
                reversed=FALSE,
                categories =c("0-4", "5-9"),
                linkedTo = 0)) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(
    labels = list(
      formatter = JS("function(){ return Math.abs(this.value) + '%'; }"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="neutral",id='neutral',color=c("#766A62"),data=list(2, 8))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Neutral",linkedTo='neutral',color=c("#ffeeff"),data=list(-5, -3))
```

Following lines are modified:

```
  hc_xAxis(list(categories = c("0-4", "5-9"),
                reversed=FALSE ), 
           list(reversed=FALSE,opposite=TRUE,
                reversed=FALSE,
                categories =c("0-4", "5-9"),
                linkedTo = 0)) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(
    labels = list(
      formatter = JS("function(){ return Math.abs(this.value) + '%'; }")))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not what I was looking for. The labels on the x Axis are going from -7.5 to 10, but I need them to go like this: 7.5   5   2.5   0   2.5   5   7.5   10. And the values of the pink bars should be 3 and 5 instead of -3 and -5

Comment: Great! This helps me a lot. Do you also know how to change the value labels? When you hover over the upper pink bar, you see '-3'. This should be 3%.

Comment: add:  hc_tooltip(shared = FALSE,
             formatter = JS("function () { return '<b>' + this.series.name + '<br/>' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);}")
  )

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, please mark your question as answered.